# How to set Postman's Authorization property in headers via variables to a value of Null / None?

Tags: variables, authorization, postman, basic-authentication, request-headers

In Postman I want to switch to different API endpoints via it's Environment feature. My first API uses Basic Auth, my second API does not use any auth.

I set up the Authorization header with variable {{auth}} as value in all my requests. In Environments {{auth}} is set to

- Basic xxx (for API 1)
- null      (for API 2)

My request works for API 1 but not for API 2. Obviously Postman tries to authorize in latter case as well and gives me an 401 (unauthorized) response. Thus I am required to deactivate the Authorization header manually whenever I want to make request to my API 2.

In Robot Framework (uses Python's requests module under the hood) I can pass
`{"Authorization": "Basic xxx`} to API 1 and
`{"Authorization": null}` to API 2 which works perfectly fine.

Is this possible with Postman? If yes - how?

### **EDIT / UPDATE:**

#### my solution (thanks to @shaochuancs)

Two ENVs for each API set in environments and a pre-request script defined
for the folder with all requests.

#### API 1 (Basic Auth):

[image]

#### API 2 (no auth):

[image]

#### Pre-Request Script:

[image]

#### Header in each request:

[image]

#### Now I can easily switch between two environments:

[image]

#### Sitenote:

Ideally I would have set `AuthKyeValue` as ENV in each environment, as well - thus would not need any pre-request script - but when I do so Postman evaluates this ENV to an empty string. Not sure why.

Comment: Do you mean to set Authorization with 2 different values?

Comment: You can modify headers using the pre-request script itself. 
 - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4631#issuecomment-477766260

Comment: @Dev kind of - two different vaules would have been easy. In my case one API uses an auth and the the other does not use auth. See my update in question for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"My first API uses Basic Auth, my second API does not use any auth."*

In that case, you can use variable for HTTP header key, make it as `"Authorization"` for the first API, and make as `undefined` for the second one -- when it is `undefined`, server won't receive that HTTP header.

[image]

The Pre-request Script would look like:

```
// For first API
pm.globals.set('AuthorizationKey', 'Authorization');
// For second API
pm.globals.set('AuthorizationKey', undefined);

pm.globals.set('AuthorizationValue', 'Basic xxxxxx');
```

Comment: `undefined` was the string I was looking for. Thank you! I was able to solve it a bit different but only with your help :). I updated my question with details of my solution.